# Why was this "copy/paste" answer undeleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, plagiarism

I flagged the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62126829/8620333) as it was a simple copy/paste of another one and it was logically deleted. Now after a *nonsense* edit it was undeleted.

## **Why?**

The edit is a kind of *joke* to me and confirms that it's indeed a copy/paste of an existing answer.

[image]

Comment: He gives proper reference to the original poster, so it's not plagiarism. An answer that shouldn't've been posted in the first place, for sure - but not plagiarism. Guess this is the sort of situation delete votes are for.

Comment: @CertainPerformance well, proper reference or not, the answer is within SO and we shouldn't do such think. We have duplicate for this.

Comment: Definitely. Unfortunately, such answers aren't against the rules, so downvotes and delete-votes are what we have to work with

Comment: I think maybe downvoting is the thing to do here. It's technically not plagiarism, perhaps that's why the moderator undeleted. For 10k above, delete-votes may also work.

Comment: @10Rep I remove the word "plagiarism" ..  it's a blant copy/past and this is what duplicate is made for and I couldn't delete an upvoted answer

Comment: The help page [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) comes in handy in such situation, as it states "Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.". which I read as: If you have nothing to add, then it's not good enough to just reference someone else's work even if you use proper attributuion.

Comment: As I type, the answer was deleted about 4 hours ago (which is also when this question was asked).  Since then, the question has also been deleted.  This all becomes moot in relation to the specific Q&A.  There may be some value in it as a general discussion of principles.

Comment: Speaking somewhat jaded, > 50% of my dupe flags end up aging away.  Some the OP even says that yes, this is a dupe.  Maybe on some of these hot tags it is better, but if I spend time finding and flagging a dupe just for nothing to happen and someone else to answer the question ... why wouldn't I just answer it so I can earn more rep to have more mod actions?

Comment: @Matt if the OP confirms that it's a dupe, ask them to confirm it by clicking on the [that solved my problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930) button. Works usually quite well. Of course, there are always users who never react on any comment, but if they already comented that it works for them, chances are that they'll click the button when you remind them.

Comment: That is absolutely not "a nonsense edit", or "a joke", it's a good edit. Link text "the answer to this question" is completely useless. Use _descriptive_ link text.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings it's a joke considering the fact that it doesn't make the answer different at all. It's like I tell you : "check this" that I later edit to make :" check this beatiful website called X to find what you want" <-- this is a joke for me.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Since when do good edits make answers different? Edits _should not_ make answers different. At 151k surely you should know this by now.

Comment: @TemaniAfif And any web developer should know that "check this" is an **awful** link text. Think you need to review the principles of the web!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I think you are completely missing the purpose of the question ... The edit is not the issue here. I am not talking about edit in general. I am talking about a specific answer where there is a copy/past from another existing answer. That answer was logically deleted and later undeleted after that *edit* which is not logical at all. Why we should undelete that answer? is it a different one after the edit? is it no more a copy/past after the edit? NO ... I don't mind if that edit make the answer look better, the answer is still a copy/past of another one

Comment: @TemaniAfif The purpose of the question is irrelevant to my comment, which merely points out that the edit is not "a nonsense edit" or "a joke" as you claimed.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings well, my claim was relevant to the question. That *specific* edit to that *specific* question is a Joke for me. If you consider the edit as a standalone thing then your comment is out of the scope of this question because I am not discussing *only* the edit here. I am discussing *why the answer was undeleted*

Comment: And that's fine. But you may wish to edit out the false claims about the edit, because they constitute an unreasonable premise for the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how it played out

1. Answer is mod flagged for plagiarism. A mod deletes it
2. User makes edits adding more links
3. User flags for undeletion and the same mod catches the flag and undeletes

Looking at the whole context, it's clear the user had a link originally and the edits didn't actually fix that. The user clearly thought they had, because they raised a flag to that effect.

Why did a mod think that it was fixed? There's two things that probably played into this

1. Most plagiarism doesn't consist of *any* mentions of the original material in the first revision
2. Most users don't attempt to fix their post and flag for undeletion

As such, a cursory scan in the mod console would show a post with an attribution link to the material. It wouldn't tell us that link existed originally. It's an easy mistake to make here.

What would have made it clearer for everyone would have been skipping the plagiarism angle in the original flag. As a commenter noted above

> He gives proper reference to the original poster, so it's not plagiarism. An answer that shouldn't've been posted in the first place, for sure - but not plagiarism. Guess this is the sort of situation delete votes are for.

It's attempting to answer the current question with an answer from another question (in other words they managed to avoid posting a link-only answer). Because of the flag, Mods reached out to this user about plagiarism, which they (to their credit) tried to fix, despite the fact that the answer was unsalvagable because the question was a duplicate (something the user should probably have explained to them).

I would still mod flag, but explain that they had merely referenced the answer from the duplicate rather than writing a new answer. That should still get it deleted, if this happens again.